# Can you load in a javascript file with HTTPS on an HTTP website?

Tags: javascript, http, https, xmlhttprequest

If I have a website called http://www.example.com .
Can I then load in an external javascript file truw HTTPS link like this: https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js ?

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Sure you can. Load the url in a <script> tag and you can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Just use a script tag as normal.

Comment: So it's not a problem to load in a javascript file with the HTTPS protocol on a HTTP page?

Comment: Nope! No problem. However, if it's an HTTPS page and an HTTP script, then you will get security warnings. But HTTP page and HTTPS script - no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have acces to the website? then it is fairly easy: 'import' this script on the webpage by setting the src to the url:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

Btw this goes in the head of your webpage.